# Newbie material on field theory

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, field-theory

I'm studying non-linear systems on my own. I have a basic idea of field diagrams for linear systems in 2d, although I'm not fully grounded in this. Are there any tutorials or material that you would recommend for a beginner. I have looked at some books eg "Nonlinear Oscillation" by Holmes, but I was overwhelmed.

Comment: Introductory differential equations texts will often illustrate solutions, stability, etc. with phase plane diagrams.  Do you have a text of this kind?

Comment: @hardmath: I am looking through the ones Amzoti recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can review these online to see if they suit your likes and needs.

- Differential Equations: A Dynamical Systems Approach, J.H. Hubbard and B. H. West
- Invitation to Dynamical Systems, E. R. Scheinerman (I believe it is also legally available as a PDF)
- Differential Equations and Their Applications, 4th Ed., M. Braun

Comment: It is demoralizing, isn't it. One can have a great day, otherwise, with accepts/upvotes. It seems all it takes is one inappropriate downvote, and it "muddy's" the otherwise-good feeling one would have.